# New battery shows white signal very soon!

Tags: battery

Bought new SF sonic flash start battery and it's just a month old. It has 3 signals..green is ok, white is needs charging and red is contact dealers.

I checked for battery indicator status and it's showing white signal very very soon.

All liquid levels are ok, battery volt reading before is 12.6 and after starting are within range 13 to 14. Alternator is ok. And the car is used normal as was before and nothing is problems except the the white signal. All warning signs etc are ok too.

Went to dealer and was told its normal and asked me to deposit with and refresh the battery which means 2 days continuous charging with them. Is this signal light too early or normal or something defective with the battery itself?

Also should I go for refreshing the battery as was advised by the dealer?

Please help me it's very worrying me.

Answer (score 0):

If the indicator you're talking about is the little bubble eye, then I doubt there's any real issue at this point. The battery just needs some prolonged charging. You'd most likely have had it go green after a couple days good use (like running around town or a road trip). The indicators are just that, an indicator. If the battery had failed to start the car or was reading low in voltage, then I'd have worried about it. A battery will lose about 1.5% of its charge every month while it sits on the shelf. I'm sure the white is just indicating it needs to catch up on this lost charge.

Comment: Yes, got recharged for 2 continuous days. Check everything ok, green signal, voltage reading ok, water level ok. Now, drive around for 5 days, at least 40 km a day, the battery is showing white signal very soon again!!!!! At this stage, any huge suspect that battery is bad???

Answer (score 0):

In asking about the battery only, you have assumed that the car's charging system (alternator, regulator, wires and connections) is operating correctly. The symptom you report, however, could also be caused by a defect or weakness in the charging system.

Thus, have the charging system examined and tested by a competent mechanic or auto electrician.